# move row inside a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UITableView that contain 3 sections, It is possible in the edit mode to change the row position just inside his section and  not to another section?Actually I can move the cell to any section.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then yes: use

```
- (NSIndexPath*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

Answer (score 8):

Many correct answers but no one presented a complete and well presented reply.

Use the table view delegate method ***tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:*** as shown below.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section != sourceIndexPath.section)
    {
        return sourceIndexPath;
    }

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

Do not forget to do another check in your ***tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:*** data source method as shown below, you do not want to run your application logic when the destination is similar to the source.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    if(sourceIndexPath == destinationIndexPath)
    {
        return;        
    }

    //application logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
if( fromIndexPath == toIndexPath ) {
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like Steven and Narayanan said, you have to implement the method

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

of your UITableView delegate.

In this method, you check the sourceIndexPath.section:

- If it's the section you allow to be reordered, you return the proposedDestinationIndexPath.
- If not, you return the sourceIndexPath so your tableView will not move the row.

I didn't write the code so you'll have the pleasure to practice instead of copy'n'paste ;)

(edit: adding list style for the options)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
 moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
```

add this check:

```
 if ( fromIndexPath.section != toIndexPath.section ) return; // prevent moving to another section.
```